# PsExec open my remote machine process but application didn't start

Tags: c#, sysinternals

I am using this code to open process in remote machine:

```
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\tools\PsExec\PsExec.exe");
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.Arguments = "\\\\192.168.0.100 -u user-p pass D:\\app.exe";
    process.StartInfo = psi;
    process.Start();
```

on the remote machine i can see that the process start but i cannot see my `Application GUI`.

Double click on the exe will open the GUI

[image]

Comment: Also, if you don't know already see http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html for a full list of arguments.

Comment: Have you tried changing `psi.CreateNoWindow` to `false`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `psexec.exe` with the `-i` switch :

```
psi.Arguments = "\\\\192.168.0.100 -i -u user -p pass D:\\app.exe";
```

or

```
psi.Arguments = "\\\\192.168.0.100 -i 0 -u user -p pass D:\\app.exe";
```

use 1 instead of 0 if you are using vista or higher. User desktop runs in session 1 in vista or higher.

Comment: Yes, via remote desktop

Comment: can u try 
psi.Arguments = @"\\192.168.0.100 -i 0 -u user -p pass D:\app.exe"

Comment: Now i get message in the remote machine: a program running on this computer is trying to display message and after click on view this message i can see my application form but the desktop is in grey and i cannot see nothing except my form until click on Return now

Comment: try 1 instead of 0 in the command if you are using vista or higher. User desktop runs in session 1 for vista or higher (for the -i flag)

Answer (score 3):

You must to specify the -i parameter with the current userID by default it is 0, in order to get the current logged user ID use: quser /SERVER:remoteComputer , in my case it returned 2, so, it is : -i 2
I hope it works for you.